# What's the term for "while(true)" loop with "break" inside?

Tags: terminology

Suppose I have a loop in C++ or C# that goes like this:

```
while( true ) {
    doSomething();
    if( condition() ) {
        break;
    }
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

This is commonly called "infinite loop". Yet it is not technically infinite - it will stop once control flows through `break`.

What's the term for such loop - that has "loop forever" loop control statement and "break" inside?

Comment: I don't think there is a special term.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that control will ever flow through break?  In that example, what if `condition()` always returns false?  I'd say it's an infinite loop with conditional breaks.

Comment: Even without a `break`, the loop is not infinite (`kill`, ctrl-alt-del, unplug...). So why bother with terminology details?

Comment: "What's the term?" - "This is commonly called infinite loop". That's your answer right there. You're clearly not be happy with the term, but that doesn't take away the fact that (natural) languages are descriptive. The "term for X" is whatever people are using, not what they should be using.

Comment: while(condition()) is not guaranteed to terminate either, both depends on condition() being true to stop.

Comment: Is this really called an "infinite loop"? I wouldn't use that term unless the loop is, you know, infinite...

Comment: I call it what it is, a "while true loop."

Also see [is while(true) bad programming practice?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390481/is-whiletrue-bad-programming-practice

Comment: @mouviciel:  IIRC, Larry Wall said that, in Ada, infinite loops would be terminated by detonation.

Comment: FWIW, `for(;;) { ... }` has no condition check and might run slightly faster (depending on your compiler or execution environment).

Comment: I think for(;;) is just less chars to type. The C++ preprocessor will optimize it anyway.

Comment: @TimWolla `for(;;) {}` doesn't throw warnings in the compiler, but `while(true) {}` might, due to having a constant as the condition.  Depends on the compiler and warning level.

Comment: And here, I thought it was just called... programming...

Comment: I think the construct `while(true)...` is what in programming is called a thread.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "name that thing" question. "Name that thing" are bad questions for the same reasons that "identify this obscure TV show, film or book by its characters or story" are bad questions: you can't Google them, they aren't practical in any way, they don't help anyone else, and allowing them opens the door for the asking of other types of marginal questions. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game

Answer (score 24):

Studying CS, this professor taught us that there are ***pre-checking loops*** (`while(cond) {}`), ***post-checking loops*** (`do {} while(cond);`), and ***middle-checking loops***. (I might have badly translated this into English, but you get the idea.)

C and C++ do not have the latter (ISTR Ada having it, BICBW), so your construct is used for that in C and C++.

Comment: Yes, Ada has this: `loop ... exit when condition; ... end loop;`

Comment: @Keith: Thanks for confirming! It's almost 20 years since I have done some Ada.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've been a professional programmer for over 20 years (and a hobbyist longer than that), and I've never heard those terms.

Comment: Regarding the translation - I think "in" is usually more fitting when "pre" and "post" are used, e.g "preorder/postorder/inorder tree traversal".

Comment: @Oak: Then that would be an _in-checking loop_? Sounds strange to me, but then I'm not a native. Feel free to elaborate.

Comment: @offby1: I thought I made it clear that I only heard this term once. That was 20 years ago.

Comment: The term I grew up with was "mid-exit loop." I've worked in a couple of different languages with explicit support for mid-exit loops.

Answer (score 13):

The very first course in CS at Stanford ([Programming Methodology by Mehran Sahami](http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=824a47e1-135f-4508-a5aa-866adcae1111)) refers to this as *a loop and a half*. And it is not necessarily bad programming practice. Consider this example on collecting user input (taken from [The Art and Science of Java by Eric Roberts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321486129), where Roberts also calls it *a-loop-and-a-half*):

```
prompt user and read in the first value
while (value != sentinel) {
    process the data value
    prompt user and read in a new value
}
```

And then the same thing solved using the *loop and a half* idea to avoid duplicate code:

```
while (true) {
    prompt user and read in a value
    if (value == sentinel) break;
    process the data value
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Lacking an official name, I'd call it the **Broken Loop**. The ambiguity of this term is intended, since a break in the middle of a loop is a bit unclean, almost like a `goto`.

Comment: I'd say, far worse than a goto.  I'd much rather see a goto than a falsly constructed condition in a loop like that.

Comment: @Brian What? The 'true' condition makes it obvious and loops like that are really common. For example, if you want to add every line of a file into a list, you have to try read the line (do something), stop if it failed (if condition break), otherwise add it to the list and repeat (do something else).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with break in the middle of a loop. If you need to carry out some operation at each start of the cycle, you will have to either duplicate the code or stuff these operations into the condition. Either variant clearly has disadvantages. `goto` also had valid applications, e.g. emulation of a try...finally block in C.

Comment: Malcolm: The possible problem is that during reading the code, it is harder to see when and why the loop is exited. Additional problems arise when you nest two or more such loops, and want to break out of the outer loop based on a condition found in the inner loop.

Comment: Let's say you have an event loop driving an Xorg application, like (in pseudo-code:) `while(XEventGet(&ev) != NULL){ ... }`, you're naturally going to want to check the keys inside the loop: `if(ev.key == XK_q) break;`. Doing the following: `while(XEventGet(&ev) != NULL && ev.key != XK_q){ ... }`, is ugly and arguably harder to read than a mid-loop break. Plus, what if something needs to be done to the value first before it can be checked? You're not seriously going to stuff all of that into the loop's base case, are you?

Answer (score 8):

There is no definitive name. Infinite loop is, I think, the appropriate term. No loops are truly infinite, but this has the potential to be effectively infinite since it's possible that the branch that contains the break will never occur.

If you tell someone "create an infinite loop, and use a break for condition X" and they'll know what you mean. If someone is reviewing your code and says nothing more than "I don't like the infinite loop you wrote" you'll know what they are talking about (unless you have more than one, of course).

Comment: It's not an infinite loop; it's got a well-defined termination condition, just like a normal `while` loop and the way you do the proof of termination is exactly the same (finding a monotonically-decreasing metric is a great start).

Answer (score 8):

It's a do-while loop with the conditional in the wrong place.

Comment: Yeah, it should be written: while(keep_going) { doSomething(); if(condition) { keep_going = false; } else { doSomethingElse(); } }

Comment: so... you're saying that if you're teaching a computer course and want to describe this, you would say "and now, we're going to learn about the *do-while loop with the conditional in the wrong place"? That sounds more like a religious opinion rather than a name.

Comment: @StephenGross That code snippet is a horrible suggestion.  Refactor to put the actual condition in the loop definition, or just use `break` or `continue`.  Avoid sentinel values at all costs, they're just another arbitrary piece of state to mentally keep track of, that disguises the purpose of the code.

Comment: Sentinal values are delayed gotos.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, yes, so they wouldn't do it.

Comment: -1 for being a single-exit weenie.

Comment: @DonalFellows, It's not that I'm being a single exit weenie, there **is** only one exit from that loop, and it's in the wrong place.

Answer (score 6):

I'd vote for **"unconditional loop"**, similar to "unconditional jump". It illustrates exactly what is going on (the code loops unconditionally), without lying (unlike "infinite loop").

Comment: But it does have a termination condition; that `if`/`break` in the middle is part of the pattern.

Answer (score 5):

> What's the term for such loop - that has "loop forever" loop control
>   statement and "break" inside?

Its an infinite loop with a break condition.

I would agree with ammilind in that if you wanted to give it a special name you could call it an **Infinite Partial Loop**

Comment: It's not infinite at all; the point where the termination condition is checked is just in a different place.

Answer (score 5):

On Rosetta Code, this particular pattern is described as an **[“N plus one half” loop](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Loops/N_plus_one_half)**. While it's not my favorite term, it's not terrible and is clearly a pattern that is useful for some kinds of loops. (The alternatives are to duplicate the before-the-condition code — potentially tricky in real programs — or to increase the nesting depth of the after-the-condition code while adding a loop condition variable; neither improves the maintainability or understandability of the code. The only reason for rejecting such constructs is if one insists on writing loops to be `break`-free.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard term, but I would say it as **Partial loop**.

This loop is used when you want to break only after **executing some part of the loop one last time** (i.e. partial execution). It's used when you don't find a suitable situation where you may want to break the *whole loop*.

In this case, you want to break the loop after at least executing `doSomething()` one last time.

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree with sbi here - I like the **middle-checking loop** term. This kind of construct was more popular when Structured Programming started to roll and many languages had syntactic support for them.

That said, it is now widespread knowledge that `while` loops are usually more mantainable, since it is easier to reason about invariants and they often handle the tricky empty case better.

In your particular case your loop is just equivalent to

```
for(; doSomething(), !condition(); doSomethingElse()){}
```

so I would only use the `break` version if either `doSomething` or `doSomethingElse` involved multiple statements and I'd rather not put them away into separate functions like you did.

That said, if your loop is more complicated then a (start, check, increment) iteration then you should consider refactoring it into something simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I guess if we are going to try to make up a term for this, maybe:

> Escapable Loop

Comment: -1. the question isn't about making up a name, it's about whether a common name already exists. Plus, all loops are "escapable" so it's not a particularly effective name.

Comment: @BryanOakley An infinite loop, by definition, shouldn't be breakable.  There probably shouldn't be a term for this, other than, bad programming.

Answer (score 0):

I call it what it is, a "while true loop."

Also see [is while(true) bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390481/is-whiletrue-bad-programming-practice)

Answer (score 0):

It is not so bad in every case. I find myself writing this kind of loops with certain kind of APIs. Say, for instance, that you have a loop object, and need to check for some condition quite deep in it, like so:

```
while (loop
    .getAExecutionModelFactory()
    .getActiveXexecutor()
    .getYCancelModelHandler()
    .getCurrentHandler()
    .isCancelled()) {
        // ... do something with the current Handler ....
        loop = ..... // prepare for next loop
}
```

Now suppose every getXXX-method could potentially return null. Then it would be still possible to write a boolean expression, although a quite complicated and unreadable one. And then we have to do redo almost the same to get at the current handler object.
In such cases, I find it easier to write a `while (true)` loop with break and continue.